# Фото переворачивается при загрузке

Tags: php, ajax, photo

Никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой - 
загружаю фото с компа - в фому, все четко. Пробую с телефона - если сфоткать горизонтально - то нормально заливает на сайт. Если же поставить вертикально то фото зальется не вертикально а горизонтально как и раньше, как это поправить? Использую ajaxupload

Answer (score 3):

Всё наоборот. При загрузке фотография как раз *не* поворачивается. А вот после загрузки её придется повернуть, самостоятельно.

Фотография при загрузке заливается как есть. Горизонтально.
Оттого, что ты повернул фотоаппарат, положение матрицы относительно объектива как бы не меняется. То есть, для фотоаппарата все фотографии - горизонтальные. Как на фотопленке: как бы ты ни вертел аппарат,  на пленке все фотографии параллельны друг другу. Точно так же сохраняются и файлы в телефоне.

Другое дело, что фотоаппарат может запомнить, как его вертели, и записать текущее положение в метаданные файла с изображением.
А практически все современные программы умеют эту информацю читать, и автоматически поворачивать фотографию. Поэтому у незадачливого зрителя складывается впечатление, что фотографии "заливаются уже повернутыми".

Так что теперь и нашему РНР программисту остается обучить свою программу этой нехитрой премудрости. Я предполагаю, что после заливки фотографии как-то обрабатываются. Вот к этой обработке и надо добавить поворот. Для GD это будет функция `imagerotate()`, а информацию об исходной ориентации можно получить с помощью функции `getImageOrientation`(). Если она недоступна - то `exif_read_data()` или с помощью каких либо ещё библиотек.